# Как измерить скорость загрузки видео с youtube?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Такая не тривиальная на первый взгляд задача. Нужно измерить скорость загрузки с youtube на андроид. Кто сталкивался с таким подскажите, может есть либы или у  youtube  усть методы в  API для этого? или ктото поделиться кодом? Есть методы измерения  http  и  ftp загрузки, но в youtube  потоковое видео и непонятно как его измерять. В идеале я вставляю ссылку на видео с  youtube  в  edittext жму на кнопку измерить, и мне в логи пишется скорость с которой загрузилось это видео.

Comment: Как предположение, можно попробовать сравнивать объем загруженной информации на момент t с объемом на момент t1, а потом просто расчитывать по формуле: ( G(t1)-G(t) )/(t1-t). Единицы измерения G(mb,kb...)/t(сек, миллисек, мин...)

Comment: А как вы загружаете?

Comment: Блин чуваки, а я о чем спрашиваю? если бы я мог загрузить видею с ютюб я бы не задавал вопроса. Сравнивать объем....конечно можно сравнивать если иметь скачаный файл. Это ютюб потому и  вопрос